# Javascript - Windows Store - Forcing Mandatory Update

Tags: javascript, uwp, win-universal-app, updates

Javascript:

I want my Windows Store app to check for updates, especially mandatory ones, and then prompt the user to update.

I have found out this involves `Windows.Services.Store`, but I cannot find any javascript examples of how this is done, only the usual c#/vb ones.

Does anyone know of a code template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have found out this involves `Windows.Services.Store`, but I cannot find any javascript examples of how this is done, only the usual c#/vb ones.

I'd suppose the examples you've found are [Code examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#code-examples) in [Download and install package updates for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates). Although, these examples are written with C#, but we can convert them to JavaScript easily as most of them are Windows Runtime APIs.

Using **Download and install all package updates** for example, the JavaScript version would like the following:

```
var context = Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext.getDefault();

context.getAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync().then(function (updates) {
    if (updates.size > 0) {
        var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Download and install updates now? This may cause the application to exit.", "Download and Install?");
        dialog.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Yes"));
        dialog.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("No"));
        dialog.showAsync().then(function (command) {
            if (command.label === "Yes") {
                context.requestDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync(updates).then(function (result) {
                    // TODO
                }, function (error) {
                    //TODO
                }, function (progress) {
                    var downloadProgressBar = document.getElementById("downloadProgressBar");
                    downloadProgressBar.value = progress.packageDownloadProgress;
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Two major differences between C# and JavaScript version here are [casing conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/jswinrt/using-the-windows-runtime-in-javascript#casing-conventions-with-windows-runtime-features) and [asynchronous methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/jswinrt/using-windows-runtime-asynchronous-methods). For more info, please see [Using the Windows Runtime in JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/jswinrt/using-the-windows-runtime-in-javascript).